# set registry key hex7

Tags: c#, windows, registry

i ve been searching for a function to set a registry key with c#.

Obvously there is the method Registry.SetValue(KEY, valueName, value, registryValueKind)

[... whereby valueName is the name of the edited value, KEY is the main key name and registryValueKind is the type of change to be made]

If you have a closer look at registryValueKind-Enum there are 8 types:

- DWord, String, ExpandString, Binary, MultiString, QWord, Unknown and
  None.

In a [Msdn-Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn789219(v=vs.85).aspx)  the different data-types are described:

- REG_SZ, REG_MULTI_SZ, REG_DWORD, REG_QWORD, REG_BINARY, REG_EXPAND_SZ, REG_HEX.

So i wonder how to store a hex(7)-value [therefore a REG_HEX-value] with the help of Registry.SetValue().

Further i wonder how to save a value like hex(7):56,00,45,00,4e,00,30,00,00,00,4c,00,4f,00,4f,00,50,00,42,\
  00,41,00,43,00,4b,00,00,00,00,00 which is, in addition to being of type hex(7) seperated by a "\".

Thanks in adavance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as "hexadecimal value", hexadecimal is just a textual representation of a binary value.

What you want is:

```
Registry.SetValue(
    "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\MyKeyName", 
    "MyValue", 
    new byte[] { 0x56, 0x00, 0x45, 0x00, 0x4e, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4c, 0x00, 0x4f, 0x00, 0x4f, 0x00, 0x50, 0x00, 0x42, 0x00, 0x41, 0x00, 0x43, 0x00, 0x4b, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }, 
    RegistryValueKind.Binary);
```