# Create a REG_NONE empty value in the Windows Registry via C#

Tags: c#, .net, registry, nonetype, registrykey

How can I create an empty value in the Windows Registry that has the type `REG_NONE`?

For instance, for this key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\
  .htm\OpenWithProgids
```

Here are the values that I see on my Windows 7 machine:

```
----------------------------------------------------
Name           Type       Data
----------------------------------------------------
(Default)      REG_SZ     (value not set)
FirefoxHTML    REG_NONE   (zero-length binary value)
htmlfile       REG_NONE   (zero-length binary value)
----------------------------------------------------
```

Specifically, how do I declare and initialize a variable of type "zero-length binary value" for the purpose of passing it to [RegistryKey.SetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k23f0345.aspx)? Note that I could not find the help that I needed in the documentation for the [RegistryValueKind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryvaluekind.aspx) enumeration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[Here is the result of my research.]*

I found the hint I was looking for in Microsoft's reference source for [RegistryKey.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/microsoft/win32/registrykey.cs):

```cs
byte[] value = new byte[0];
```

Specifically, call [RegistryKey.SetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.setvalue?view=net-6.0) where:

- `name` is set to the name you want for the key,
- `value` is set to an [empty byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727146/how-do-i-initialize-an-empty-array-in-c/8727172#8727172), and
- `valueKind` is set to [RegistryValueKind.None](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryvaluekind?view=net-6.0).

```cs
 using Microsoft.Win32;

 RegistryKey key; // set via 'CreateSubKey' or 'OpenSubKey'
 key.SetValue("KeyName", new byte[0], RegistryValueKind.None);
```

However, note that at least for values that appear in an `OpenWithProgids` key, Windows also appears to treat *empty string* values as equivalent:

```cs
 key.SetValue("KeyName", string.Empty, RegistryValueKind.String);
```

For instance, for this key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.vcxproj\OpenWithProgids
```

Here are the values that I see on my machine:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
Name                                  Type      Data
---------------------------------------------------------------
(Default)                             REG_SZ    (value not set)
Expression.Blend.vcsproj.12.0         REG_SZ
VisualStudio.Launcher.vcxproj.10.0    REG_SZ
VisualStudio.Launcher.vcxproj.12.0    REG_SZ
VisualStudio.vcxproj.10.0             REG_SZ
VisualStudio.vcxproj.12.0             REG_SZ
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Related:** See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087240/how-to-write-binary-data-as-is-to-registry-ie-i-have-visible-binary-data-as/5091379#5091379) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38480659/set-registry-key-hex7/38480818#38480818) for examples for how to set the data of a Registry value of type `RegistryValueKind.Binary` to a *non-empty* byte array.